# Android Application without Classes?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have seen a JS talk about Redux recently. The speaker programmed a working application without any classes, just with const variables. He even excluded classes in his lint file (https://github.com/MartinSeeler/redux-presentation/tree/master/demo).

So I tried to do the same in my Android apps, which are written in Kotlin. Unfortunately, I get the following error when I try to make my MainActivity class an object:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{blog.app.niklas.flyingbytes/blog.app.niklas.flyingbytes.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: void blog.app.niklas.flyingbytes.MainActivity.<init>() is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.Instrumentation>
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: void blog.app.niklas.flyingbytes.MainActivity.<init>() is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.Instrumentation>
```

Is there a way to work around this? I really like the idea of having as many singleton objects as possible in my app.

Thank you in advance,

Niklas

Comment: How do you know `{AppContainer} from 'react-hot-loader';` is not a translated into an Activity class? That's the entry point of the Redux render in index.js, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Geoffrey said, the Android platform manages your activities, but that also means that the platform is responsible for keeping track of your Activity's instances - which is the purpose of Singleton.

So, while you can't make your Activity an object, you can still make it a Singleton by using the `android:launchMode` attribute in your `AndroidManifest`:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
```

For more information on the launchMode attribute (including other possible values), check out the [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

Comment: I am able to launch into MainActivityKotlin.kt if I add the line: `apply plugin: "kotlin-android"` to the app `build.gradle` file.   Without this line, I get the same error.   Note that the "configure Kotlin for project" action in Android Studio adds a kotlin project to the top level `build.gradle` file with the line: `apply plugin: 'kotlin'`.   Kotlin version level as of this writing is 1.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

You can't replace Activity class by kotlin object on Android, for the same reason you don't instantiate Activities by calling it's constructor: 
activities are managed by the platform.

When you ask (via an Intent) the platform for an Activity, the platform will try to instantiate it by calling it's constructor with zero parameter. Which doesn't exist for an object, giving the mentioned error.

That's said, some developer dodge around the frame given by Android, like [mortar](https://github.com/square/mortar), by having only one activity and using custom logic for navigation between views.